# How to measure execution time across VS 2008 C++ and Unity C# programs on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2008, profiling

I have two programs which communicate via UDP running on a Windows 7 machine. One is built in VS 2008 with C++ and the other is a Unity3D program using C# scripts. I'd like to take the highest precision possible measurements of execution time in both programs that are on the same timeline, so that I can measure how much time passes between various events across the two programs.

I can't use .NET's System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class, as I normally would within say the Unity C# scripts, because a stopwatch has to be "started" within a program and so won't be in sync with the other program. Meanwhile, System.Environment.TickCount measures in milliseconds since the system was started, which sounds promising, but isn't very precise, with an actual granularity (apparently) of around 15 ms.

What should I be doing?

Comment: What are you measure that requires microsecond precision? The closest thing I can think of is `QueryPerformanceCounter`, but there's a bunch of caveats with using it.

Comment: @yiding, it's for an HCI application. The C++ program processes the input an communicates it to the Unity program. I need to reduce the latency in this input loop as much as possible.

Comment: Any chance of getting windows 8? [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx) gives microsecond resolution system time. There's also the less precise sibling `GetSystemTimeAsFileType`. Just run these in a loop and see the resolution you get, of course printing out the values may take multiple microseconds.